# NoClassDefFoundFor Paypal REST SDK and Paycorp (Gateway Jar)

Tags: grails, dependency-management

**grailsVersion=3.2.3
gradleWrapperVersion=3.0**

I have gradle dependency  **compile group: 'com.paypal.sdk', name: 'rest-api-sdk', version: '1.14.0'** in build gradle and during war creation jar is available in /WEB-INF/lib/ but it is continuously showing **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.paypal.base.rest.JSONFormatter** although this specific class is available in that sdk-jar. (JSONFormatter.class is also created)

```
ERROR StackTrace - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch
failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
initialize class com.paypal.base.rest.JSONFormatter     at
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:978)
    at
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter.doFilter(RestLogoutFilter.groovy:80)
    at
org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.processFilterChain(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:118)
    at
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.doFilter(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:84)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RestAuthenticationFilter.groovy:143)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at
org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at
org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
    at
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
    at
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:94)
    at
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:112)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
com.paypal.base.rest.JSONFormatter     at
com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalModel.toJSON(PayPalModel.java:14)     at
com.paypal.api.payments.Payment.create(Payment.java:148)     at
com.ivalley.payment.PaypalService.$tt__createPayment(PaypalService.groovy:104)
    at
grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
    at
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at
grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
    at
com.ivalley.payment.PaymentService.$tt__paypalTransaction(PaymentService.groovy:64)
    at
grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
    at
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at
grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
    at
com.ivalley.payment.PaymentService.$tt__transactionThePayment(PaymentService.groovy:26)
    at
grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
    at
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at
grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
    at
com.ivalley.payment.PaymentController.completePayment(PaymentController.groovy:58)
    at
org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$MethodHandleInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:222)
    at
org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:187)
    at
org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    ... 38 common frames omitted ERROR
org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - NoClassDefFoundError
occurred when processing request: [POST] /makePayment Could not
initialize class com.paypal.base.rest.JSONFormatter. Stacktrace
follows: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler
dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
Could not initialize class com.paypal.base.rest.JSONFormatter     at
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:978)
    at
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter.doFilter(RestLogoutFilter.groovy:80)
    at
org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.processFilterChain(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:118)
    at
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.doFilter(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:84)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RestAuthenticationFilter.groovy:143)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at
org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at
org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
    at
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
    at
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:94)
    at
org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:112)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
com.paypal.base.rest.JSONFormatter     at
com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalModel.toJSON(PayPalModel.java:14)     at
com.paypal.api.payments.Payment.create(Payment.java:148)     at
com.ivalley.payment.PaypalService.$tt__createPayment(PaypalService.groovy:104)
    at
grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
    at
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at
grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
    at
com.ivalley.payment.PaymentService.$tt__paypalTransaction(PaymentService.groovy:64)
    at
grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
    at
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at
grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
    at
com.ivalley.payment.PaymentService.$tt__transactionThePayment(PaymentService.groovy:26)
    at
grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
    at
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at
grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
    at
com.ivalley.payment.PaymentController.completePayment(PaymentController.groovy:58)
    at
org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$MethodHandleInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:222)
    at
org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:187)
    at
org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

This code is working well in local Grails run-app command very well.Anyone having same issue?

And similar issue I have been suffering with gateway-client-java-1.5.6.jar which is external Java Jar and also available in war.

Comment: That's a `Could not initialize class com.paypal.base.rest.JSONFormatter` error... is there more stacktrace?  I think a class is missing, but not necessarially `com.paypal.base.rest.JSONFormatter`, something else...

Comment: This is all I have found in console. I suspected whether other dependent jars(classes) are missing but couldn't found. All Jars/classes in local are seems to be available in war. Most importantly it is working in my local linux machine, using grails run-app.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came to sort out the things 
Instead of

> **compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"**

updating dependency to

> **compile group: 'org.grails', name: 'grails-dependencies', version:
>   '3.3.3', ext: 'pom'**

solved the case